# Redux how to check if user is logged in inside auth reducer state parameter using sessions

Tags: reactjs, session, cookies, redux

Below, from what I've seen, is a pretty standard reducer signature for handling token based authentication:

```
function auth(state = {
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? true : false
  }, action)
```

The **`isAuthenticated`** property checks if user is logged in based on whether token exists in localStorage, how would I do the same If I'm using session authentication with cookies?

Would it be sufficient to write a function that retrieves cookie from document.cookie based on its name and using it in exactly the same way as the example code above?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Redux Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to fire an action after the application has mounted. This provides the session token to the reducer state, rather than querying it directly from inside the reducer, or its initialization method. It's best not to do any asynchronous processing or data fetching inside your reducers.

I'll show an example of handling this sort of asynchronous data initialization using Redux Saga.

First, fire an action at an appropriate point in the app lifecycle. For example:

```
class App extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
       SessionActionCreators.applicationMounted();
   }
}
```

You can register to listen to this action via your middleware (as for redux-saga):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import reducer from './reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

let store = {};

export default function configureStore() {

    let enhancer = compose(
         applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
    );    

    store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
}

export function getStore() {
    return store;
}
```

In your `rootSaga` you can initialize a `startup` saga that

```
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import startup from './startup';
...

function* rootSaga() {
    yield [
        fork(startup),
        ...
    ];
}

export default rootSaga;
```

**startup.js**

```
import {call, put, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { APPLICATION_MOUNTED } from '../constants/app';
import { getSessionTokenSuccess } from '../actions';

function getSessionAuth() {
    let token;
    let cookies = document.cookie;
    // do whatever processing you need to do to ensure the session
    // token is present and valid
    return token;
}

function handleStartup() {
    const sessionAuth = yield call(getSessionAuth);
    if (sessionAuth) {
        yield put(getSessionTokenSuccess(sessionAuth));
    }
}

export default function* startup() {
    yield takeEvery(APPLICATION_MOUNTED, handleStartup);
}
```

The action would have the following signature:

**actions.js**

```
export const getSessionTokenSuccess(token) => {
    return {
        type: GET_SESSION_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
        payload: token
    }
}
```

In your reducer, listen for `GET_SESSION_TOKEN_SUCCESS`:

```
function auth(state = {
    isFetching: false,
    isAuthenticated: false
  }, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_SESSION_TOKEN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                sessionToken: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

You can be more robust about this by placing the `yield call(getSessionAuth)` in a `try ... catch`, and also dispatching (via `put`) a `GET_SESSION_TOKEN_FAILURE` action if the token is not found or the try fails. But the above reducer setup defaults authentication to false and only sets it to `true` if the token is found. The reducer only ever establishes `isAuthenticated` as `true` in response to an action dispatched by the application.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with redux-saga, I've already implemented the async part of this using Redux-thunk. My question is just to verify whether i can do the same thing as was done in the token example inside the auth reducer, but instead of checking if token exists in localStorage check if cookie exists inside document.cookie

Comment: It's fine if you're using redux-thunk, but simply respond to the action it dispatches using the reducer switch statement, rather than on initialization. Treat whatever process you're doing to evaluate the presence of the session token as async and resolve the value out of the action dispatched by your thunk. Do not do asynchronous processing in your state initializer.

Comment: There is no async processing in state initializer anyway, the example contains:  isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('id_token') ? true : false, this isn't an async action, it's a lookup inside localStorage, and all i'm trying to ask if the same could be done with document.cookie

Comment: Even if it isn't async in practice, it's an anti-pattern to do localStore.getItem() or document.cookie inside your initializer. You're essentially hydrating your store: this should be done with an action. You can also initialize your store when you first create it: 

You may optionally specify the initial state as the second argument to createStore(). 

This is useful for hydrating the state of the client to match the state of a Redux application running on the server.

`let store = createStore(todoApp, window.STATE_FROM_SERVER)`

[source](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html)